# Javascript setting CSS using variables

Tags: javascript, css, variables

I've made a function that creates a grid of squares. When I manually set the height and width in the CSS to 30px, everything works with a 16x16 grid in a 480px x 480px container. The idea is to fit other amounts of squares in the same space, so I have to set the height and width by variable.

```
function makeGrid() {
var $grid = $('#container');
var height = 480 / numOfSides;
var width = 480 / numOfSides;
  $('.gridSquare').css({'height':height+'px','width':width+'px'});
  for (i = 0; i < numOfSides; i++) {
    var row = '<div>';
      for (j = 0; j < numOfSides; j++)
        row += '<div class="gridSquare"></div>';
        row += '</div>';
        $grid.append(row);
  }
}
```

However, the code I'm using now generates one square. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong in using these variables and the css method?

Comment: Your current code creates a new dov at the beginning of each row, then create a new one in it, closes the first one, then possibly creates a new div, then closes the first one again (wich won't wok because it' already closed)

Comment: What is `numOfSides`? Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the css on gridSection at the end of the loop, otherwise, it doesn't get applied to the last row.

```
var numOfSides = 5;

function makeGrid() {
  var $grid = $('#container');
  var height = 480 / (numOfSides);
  var width = 480 / (numOfSides);

  for (i = 0; i < numOfSides; i++) {
      var row = '<div>';

      for (j = 0; j < numOfSides; j++) {
        row += '<div class="gridSquare"></div>';

      }
      row += '</div>';
      $grid.append(row);
  }
  $('.gridSquare').css({'height':height+'px','width':width+'px'});
}

makeGrid();
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/nobrien/pen/bpLGXK